# Prevent mouse and keyboard event capturing inside a div for all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a site containing a forms that is saved using jquery autosave and updated using ajax. This form contains different types of input element like  textbox, jquery-ui datepicker and timepicker...

```
<div id="body">
  <form id="line1">
    <input id="1" type="text"/>
    <input id="2" type="text" class="datepicker"/>
    <input id="3" type="text" class="timepicker"/>
    <select id="4" multiple="multiple>
       <option> 1 </option>
    </select>
  </form>
  <form id="line2">
    <input id="1" type="text"/>
    <input id="2" type="text" class="datepicker"/>
    <input id="3" type="text" class="timepicker"/>
    <select id="4" multiple="multiple">
       <option> 1 </option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
```

Now I need to reload the content for body for filtering purposes.
What now can happen is that the content is reloaded and while the forms still accept inputs and try to save it but after reload it "disappears" because it wasn't taken into the new view. 
Adding an overlay with pointer-events:none stopped mouse events but typing is still possible.

What I already have tried is:

```
 function disableDiv(event)
 {
    event.stopimmediatepropagation()
 }

 ... 
 this.element.find('.body')[0].addEventListener("keydown", disableDiv, true);
```

Which seam to work for Firefox but not for Chrome or IE

Is there a way to prevent keyboard events to capturing into the forms for every browser?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I totally understand your question. But have you tried making your jQuery set all of your inputs to `disabled` when the form is submitted? That would accomplish the goal of not letting your inputs be changed after the form is submitted.

For example:

**jQuery 1.6+**

```
$("input").prop('disabled', true);
```

**jQuery 1.5 and below**

```
$("input").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

You could get some ideas from how bootstrap marks inputs disabled, if you're unfamiliar... http://getbootstrap.com/css/.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your inputs to not be able to be edited, the correct way to do it is to disable them. Something like this would do it:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".datepicker").datepicker();
  
  $("#disable").click(function() {
    $("#body input").prop( "disabled", true );
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="body">
  <form id="line1">
    <input id="1" type="text"/>
    <input id="2" type="text" class="datepicker"/>
    <input id="3" type="text" class="timepicker"/>
    <select id="4" multiple="multiple>
       <option> 1 </option>
    </select>
  </form>
  <form id="line2">
    <input id="1" type="text"/>
    <input id="2" type="text" class="datepicker"/>
    <input id="3" type="text" class="timepicker"/>
    <select id="4" multiple="multiple">
       <option> 1 </option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>

<input type="button" value="disable" id="disable"/>
```

Obviously you can re-enable them once you are done loading whatever it is you are loading.

Trying to prevent the specifics of how you might interact with the control rather than what state you want the control to be in, is doing the wrong way. You don't care if somebody clicks or types, what you care about is that the control can't be edited. For example, you have stopped click and keydown, but what about touch events? Or any other type of event that some browser somewhere might implement for interacting with a control. If you try to disable a control by intercepting only the events that cause the control to do something then there is always the risk that you miss some interaction.

Comment: Indeed this is working for normal inputs. JQuery-UI components like datepicker allow changing of disabled input fields. What I'm looking for is a generic way not involving all the proprietary disable calls of the ui extensions. IMHO preventing the event capturing by the outer div is the only way?

Comment: @Steve: *"JQuery-UI components like datepicker allow changing of disabled input fields."* no they don't. I added JQueryUI and set the `.datepicker` to be a datepicker. Setting the disable property (which is NOT proprietary - it's part of standard HTML) disables the datepicker *exactly like you'd expect*. Even capturing to disable something is exactly *not* how to do it. Any UI control that doesn't respect the `disabled` attribute is fundamentally broken.